# How to stop and play owl carousel onclick item

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

How to stop and play owl carousel onclick item, this my code

```
 $('.hero-area').on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
      owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
    } else{
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');` to stop the carousel.

And you can try this:

```
 $('.hero-area').on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('clicked')){
      owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
    } else{
    owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
   }
 });
```

See more here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var owl = $("#owl-banner");
owl.trigger('owl.stop');
```